# How can I create jade elements dynamically in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, pug

I am new at coding and stuck somewhere, cause I need a bit of help. I have a basic jade template with `a`, `h2`, and `div` tags

```
h2
  a(href='/'+ '#{postId}')  #{title}
.content   #{contentText}
```

and here I find and send the first `title`, `text`, and `postId` to my jade template

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    const findPost = postInfo.find({}).then((data) => {
        posts.push(...data);

        res.render('index' , {
            title: posts[0].title,
            contentText: posts[0].content,
            postId: posts[0].postId
        });
    });
});
```

Now I need to create the same pug elements but the values have to come from the `posts[1]` array then create pug again and now values come from `posts[2]`. I have to do this multiple times but don't know how. Can anyone give me a tip?

Comment: Read https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html. (Go over the rest of the documentation as well, you might be missing other important stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally do it. You can send you whole array to the jade template and use your data like this:

```js
var posts = []

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     const findPost = postInfo.find({}).then((data)=>
     {
     posts = [...data]
     res.render('index' , {posts: posts});

     });
          });
```

```html
- for(var i = 0; i<5;i++){

 .content-div
  h2
    a(href='/'+ '#{posts[i].postId}')  #{posts[i].title}  
  .content #{posts[i].content}
  -}
```